# Loading data into chart on html page

Tags: html, node.js, chart.js

I am attempting to create a webpage that creates a simple chart using chart.js. I want to store all data related to the chart into a separate file `./file.json`. When I attempt to load the html  page while attempting to load data from `./file.json` into `chartdata`, the chart fails to appear, but when I insert the data directly into `script.js`, it works.

Here is my faulty code within the script:

```
const chartdata = require('./file.json');
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels:[ 'Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Dick' ],
        datasets:[{
            label: 'population',
            data: chartdata
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

The chart successfully appears in the html page when I insert the data directly:

```
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels:[ 'Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Dick' ],
        datasets:[{
            label: 'population',
            data: [135850, 52122, 148825, 16939, 9763]
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data to charts.js as an array instead of just as a JSON file. I've included an example below. It uses the fs library, which **i think** is included in node by default.

```
const fs = require("fs");
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

// read file sample.json file
fs.readFile('./file.json',
    // callback function that is called when reading file is done
    function(err, data) { 
        // json data
        var jsonData = data;
 
        // parse json
        var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    }
);

let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels:[ 'Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Dick' ],
        datasets:[{
            label: 'population',
            data: jsonParsed
        }]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your code, but I still have the same problem: the browser is not loading the chart anymore.

Comment: Try using `console.log(jsonParsed);` to make sure that it is in the format you need it in - if it's not then at least we know what it is so we can convert it. Also, the reason for the chart not loading in, could be an error in your code somewhere. It could be anywhere in the file messing up. Check the console in Developer Tools (F12 in most browsers)

Comment: It doesn't console.log. I also get the following errors in my console:               
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/contentscript.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/inpage.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Those console errors have nothing to do with the project I suspect and more to do with errors in extensions you have installed. Where have you put `console.log(jsonParsed);`? You might have put it somewhere that doesn't get run? Try putting it just before `let massPopChart`, if that isn't where it is already.

Comment: Just realised - jsonParsed might not be accessible outside of `fs.readFile()`. Try this code: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/DXaCAs4i)